# SetForegroundWindow on macOS using C#

Tags: c#, macos, avaloniaui

On Windows I can set a window to be in foreground using this code:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
...
var process = Process.Start(start);
IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
```

How can this be achieved on macos with .net 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AvaloniaUI you can do this in cross-platform fashion using [`Window.Topmost`](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/WindowBase/83FCB77B).

This is how you would create a window in XAML that will always be on top:

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:AlwaysOnTop.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="AlwaysOnTop.Views.MainWindow"
        Topmost="True"
        Title="AlwaysOnTop">

</Window>
```

Comment: I'd don't want it topmost all the time. I need to activate the window on a specific event.

Comment: What stops you from setting it to `true`, when your specific event occurs and then to `false` afterwards?

Comment: God point. I will try that!